# Difference - unless / if

Tags: ruby

Can anyone explain me the difference between `if` and `unless` and when to use it?

Comment: `unless comments.empty?` looks nicer than `if !comments.empty?`, but using it with an else clause, like: `unless comments.empty? then aaa else bbb end` may be more confusing than the reversed equivalent:  `if comments.empty? bbb else aaa end`

Comment: Ruby does not follow the Zen of Python: "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`unless` is just a negated `if`. That is, it executes whatever it contains if the condition is *not* true.

```
unless foo?
    # blabla
end
```

Simply means

```
if !foo?
    # blabla
end
```

It's all a matter of what you find easier to read, really.

See also: [Unless, The Abused Ruby Conditional](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2008/12/01/unless-the-abused-ruby-conditional/)

Comment: For some reason, I find it incredibly confusing to read `unless` statements. Is there anyone else in the same situation?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon You're definitely not alone.

Answer (score 11):

Using 'unless' is straightforward to me when there is one argument, but I find it confusing when there are several. And when using `||` instead of `&&`.

*"Unless this or that"* is just harder for my brain. *"if not this and not that"* is easier.

It's going to be harder to maintain this code in the future if I use it.  So I don't.

Comment: Remember De Morgan's Law when in doubt.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 8):

`unless` is simply equivalent to `if not`. When you use which is a personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `if` and `unless` is that they are exact opposites of each other:

- `if` takes a condition, a then-block and an optional else-block, and it evaluates the then-block if the condition is truthy, otherwise it evaluates the else-block
- `unless` takes a condition, a then-block and an optional else-block, and it evaluates the then-block if the condition is falsy, otherwise it evaluates the else-block

Or, in other words: they mean pretty much the same thing in Ruby as they do in English.

Comment: Your text above seems misleading given the ability for post conditionals. (While the distinction between the two is correct, the rest implies that you need a `then` block, and that you might always choose to put an `else` block.)

Answer (score 1):

As a ruby on rails dev its best to follow best practices maintain code readability. My answer is not directly related to this question but it might help someone, Try using `if` as much as possible instead of `unless` For example, instead of `unless comments.empty?` its better to use `if comments.present?`, instead of `unless comments.present?` try using `if comments.blank?`, `blank?` checks for both `empty` and `nil`.