# Ruby: unless vs if not

Tags: ruby, coding-style

I find myself preferring `if not` rather than `unless`. Is there a proper way to write that sort of condition? How do people generally feel about `unless`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference - unless/if](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806452/difference-unless-if)

Comment: the other one is asking for the difference, this asks for style guideline.

Comment: The other says "when to use it", which I interpreted as style.

Comment: I'm curious to know how people structure operations with easily reversible conditions... such as `foo if bar.persisted?` vs `foo unless bar.new_record?`

Comment: given the choice, I'd go for the more positive-sounding one.

Comment: [Read this post ‘unless’ you’re not a Ruby developer](https://jesseduffield.com/Unless/)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I hope this helps you: https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#if-vs-unless

> Prefer unless over if for negative conditions (or control flow ||).
>
> ```
> # bad
> do_something if !some_condition
>
> # bad
> do_something if not some_condition
>
> # good
> do_something unless some_condition
> ```

I personally agree with what's written there choosing `unless something` over `if !something` for modifiers and simple ones and when there's an `else` prefer `if`.

Comment: haha well lucky for me then he used that example. One thing though since you mentioned the `case` statement, you may want to read what others have to say about it:
http://www.rubyflow.com/items/6495-the-totally-unofficial-ruby-coding-style-guide 
and  
http://batsov.com/Programming/Ruby/2011/09/12/ruby-style-guide.html and I also agree that `when/else` inside `case` should be idented.

Comment: This is the exact Style Guide's link https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#unless-for-negatives @derp mentioned in his answer

Answer (score 42):

I use `unless` every time, except when there is an `else` clause.

So, I'll use

```
unless blah_blah
  ...
end
```

but if there is an else condition, I'll use `if not` (or `if !`)

```
if !blah_blah
 ...
else
 ...
end
```

After using `if !` for years and years and years, it actually took me a while to get used to `unless`. Nowadays I prefer it in every case where reading it out loud sounds natural.

I'm also a fan of using a trailing `unless`

`increment_by_one unless max_value_reached` I'm using these method/variable names obviously as a readability example - the code's structure should basically follow that pattern, in my opinion.

In a broader sense, the structure should be: `take_action unless exception_applies`

Comment: Instead `if !blah_blah a else b end` I would use `if b else a end` (switch the if- and else-part and skip the 'not').

Comment: But you skipped the condition? But yeah, assuming the code blocks where of similar size, otherwise I'll put the smaller one on top to avoid having to scan down a long way for the other condition's code.

Comment: @knut - yes, but in complex conditionals it's not always possible, such as when you have `if a or !b` where one part of the condition has a `not` on it - but yes, you can obviously switch the order if it works for the specific conditional you're writing.

Comment: Did you mean you use `unless` every time, unless there is an `else` clause?

Comment: I have come to a realization that "unless"; while more expressive, is significantly more likely to confuse readers than "if not". I was writing a Perl program a minute ago that read `unless ($#ARGV + 1) { die "no arguments";}` which while short, seems to sound more like a threat you are making to your own program than a statement. `if ((scalar @ARGV) == 0) { die "no arguments";}` is much more readable. Everyone understands ifs; it takes a much more experienced reader to understand `unless` as easily as `if`.

Comment: @Dmitry - I felt the same way at first (that it required a much more experienced reader), until one day I was puzzling over `if` vs `unless` openly to my wife, who does not work in a technical field. Turns out she understood the difference immediately, and explained it back to me, which caused the proverbial light bulb to turn on for me.

The point of my story being that I think we (programmers) often talk about readability when we really mean familiarity, and that we overestimate the cost of learning new things. Sometimes a new thing is just hard for us, but not objectively hard. :)

Comment: @jefflunt readability DOES equal familiarity, but when someone is reading your code and you are not there to explain unless vs if, its almost certain that it will either confuse them or make them use more mental resources to wrap their head around the expression. unless Isnt hard, but lots of choose mixing if and unless sometimes at start(if food.edible) food.consume) and sometimes at end(food.consume if food.edible). People deal with complexity through patterns, expressiveness is fantastic, but it can harm readability without committing to some style patterns.

Comment: if I replace every if in the Linux kernel with an unless macro, it's going to take a long time to adapt even though the two express the same thing but inversed.

Comment: Agreed. And I should qualify my statement by saying that I'm only talking about Ruby code in this context, and not the Linux kernel or other projects.

Also, wasn't suggesting that every `if` be replaced.

Answer (score 12):

`if not condition` is rarely used. Ruby programmers (usually coming from other languages) tend to prefer the use `if !condition`.

On the other side, unless is widely use in case there is a single condition and if it sounds readable.

Also see [making sense with Ruby unless](http://rubyist.info/style/#making-sense-with-rubys-unless-1) for further suggestions about unless coding style.

Comment: I'd highlight _"in case there is a single condition and if it sounds readable"_. Readability is the king!