# What's the major difference between if statements and unless statements?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, statements

I am new to programming and I don't understand what the difference is. I am coding in Ruby.

Comment: basic difference is your sight on many things. For example: you should terminate program(function) if array is empty. `if array.empty?` - good choice. But it doesn't make sense if your parameter `array` is `nil`. So, you prefer to terminate program if array not nil. it can be checked as `unless array`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806452/difference-unless-if

Answer (score 1):

if should be obvious: execute a block of code if the condition is true.

unless is the opposite: execute a block of code if the condition is false.

http://www.codecademy.com/glossary/ruby/if-unless-elsif-and-else

Comment: So basically just an automatically negated if statement.

Answer (score 0):

`unless` is equal to `if not`

for example:

```
a= false

unless a
  puts "hello"
end

=> hello

if not a
  puts "hello"
end

=> hello
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the goals of Ruby language is to become more closer to the real English. And keywords `if` and `unless` are really good examples of that. Look at this:

```
if animal.can_speak?
  animal.say 'Woof!'
end

# moreover, it can be transformed in one-line, which looks pretty awesome:
animal.say 'Woof!' if animal.can_speak?
```

`unless` is an opposite of the `if` and instead of writing:

```
if not animal.can_speak?
  puts "This animal can't speak"
end
```

we can use `unless`, that usually **considered as more natural way**:

```
unless animal.can_speak?
  puts "This animal can't speak"
end

# it also has one-line approach:
puts "..." unless animal.can_speak?
```