# Is there an "unless" function in java or Processing? Something that runs code unless a certain parameter is met?

Tags: java, function, processing

This might be a stupid thing to ask but is there something that does this:

```
unless (boolean==true){
       do aThing;
} otherwise {
       do somethingElse;
}
```

EDIT: I don't mean an "if/else" statement. I'm pretty familiar with those.

Here's a more accurate example of what I'm talking about:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

int amountOfThings= in.nextInt();

for (int i = 0; i <=amountOfThings;i++){

unless (amountOfThings==20){
System.out.println(i);
 }
}
```

Comment: `if (!whatever)`

Comment: If is called `if(!(` `))` -- no syntactical candy for that, the language is complete and fully understandable without that.

Comment: I guess you come from ruby or something where the unless keyword exists, you have to live without it in java unfortunately, not that hard to read "if amount is not 20"

Comment: Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Like what everyone else here is saying, what you're asking for just seems to be an if/else statement.

Comment: [Unless is just a negated if](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4806484/5217712). Java don't have that but you have if-else.

Comment: If you don't mean an `if`, you probably mean a `while` or a `break`. Or an `if` nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

Couple options:

```
if(thing){
   //do the thing
}
else{
   //do the other thing
}
```

This checks if `thing` is true, and if it is it executes the first block. If it's not, then it executes the `else` block.

Or you could use the `!` not operator:

```
if(!thing){
   //do the other thing
}
```

This uses the `!` not operator, which reverses `thing`. In other words this checks if `thing` is false, and if so it executes the code block.

**Edit:** Your example would be this:

```
if (amountOfThings != 20){
   System.out.println(i);
}
```

Shameless self-promotion: [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/if-statements) is a tutorial on `if` statements in Processing.

Comment: I guess I should probably explain what I mean a bit better.

Comment: The code in a block of an if-else will not be executed and will not cost you any performance if it is not entered - if that was your question.
However it will be present in the final java-byte-code (class-file). There is no such preprocessor stuff in Java (at least not directly) as in other languages like C.

Answer (score 0):

No. 
You can also not put the 'if' or 'unless' condition at the end of the statement.

If it helps you feel any better I met many people who complained about the fact that it does exist in Perl.