# How to convert this if condition to unless?

Tags: ruby

```
if array.present?
 puts "hello"
end
```

There is no else part to this.

How to write the above `if` condition using `unless`.

I'm asking this question because of this lint error:

> Use a guard clause instead of wrapping the code inside a conditional expression

Comment: Where does `present?` come from? Rails?

Comment: Yeah. Sorry, Forgot to mention it. `array.present?` will be true or false.

Comment: "There is else part" has nothing to do with selecting `if` vs `unless`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46224353/how-to-convert-this-if-condition-to-unless#comment79412384_46224549):

> I'm asking this question because of this lint error
>
> > Use a guard clause instead of wrapping the code inside a conditional expression

This means that instead of:

```
def foo(array)
  if array.present?
    puts "hello"
  end
end
```

You are supposed to use:

```
def foo(array)
  return unless array.present?
  puts "hello"
end
```

See https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-nested-conditionals

If this is a Rails question ([is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46224353/how-to-convert-this-if-condition-to-unless#comment79411804_46224353)), you can also use [`blank?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F):

```
def foo(array)
  return if array.blank?
  puts "hello"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

**There's no reason to.**

Remember:  `unless` is [the inverse of `if`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4806484/1079354) (or `!if` if you rather), and is only intended to make your code *easier* to read.

Using `unless` with your expression would be *incredibly* awkward, because you're now moving the actual body of work to an `else` statement...

```
unless array.present?
  return
else
  puts "hello"
end
```

...which doesn't make your code any easier to read if you had stuck with a  negated `if`:

```
if !array.present?
  return
else
  puts "hello"
end
```

**Don't use `unless` here.** You lose readability in exchange for virtually nothing.

Comment: moreover, if it's a method call like above. I will personally be inclined to have the return statement as sort of guard clause. `return if !array.present?` and then carry on with puts "hello" and stuff.

Comment: I'm asking this question because of this lint error 
`Use a guard clause instead of wrapping the code inside a conditional expression`

Comment: @normanbates:  Your linter should be helping you out, not totally getting in the way of readable code.  I personally find the above perfectly fine; your linter seems overly zealous in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

```
unless array.present?
  return
else
  puts "hello"
end
```

**OP requested one-liner modification:**

Pseudocode:

```
something unless condition
```

Therefore:

```
puts "hello" unless !array.present?
```

Comment: Thanks, can we do it one line?

Comment: Edited for one-liner. See above.

Comment: `unless array.blank?`

Comment: I forgot the `!` before `array.present?`, but yes I believe that would work as well, Sergio.

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
puts "hello" unless !array.present?
```

However, I would recommend:

```
puts "hello" if array.present?
```

Comment: How is the above line working?
If array.present? is true, it will return nil.
If array.present? is false, then only it will return "hello".
is that right?

Comment: Then the old if condition behavior will be just opposite of this block of code, right?
I want "hello" to be printed when `array.present?` is true

Comment: Then you can use the code you posted, it's perfectly fine already. You don't need `unless`.

Comment: `unless !array.present?` == `unless array.blank?`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev awesome.